# How to iterate associative array and delete some elements in JSLint way (JavaScript, node.js 4.2.3)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jslint

I wrote code:

```
for (var game in this.currentGames) {
    if (this.currentGames[game].gameState === consts.GS_GAME_DELETE) {
        delete this.currentGames[game];
    }
}
```

It works fine, but JSLint.net show me warning:

JSLint : Unexpected 'var'.

When I tried to fix it:

```
var game;
for (game in this.currentGames) {
    if (this.currentGames[game].gameState === consts.GS_GAME_DELETE) {
        delete this.currentGames[game];
    }
}
```

I get such warning:
JSLint : Expected 'Object.keys' and instead saw 'for in'.

I tried to fix and wrote next code:

```
Object.keys(this.currentGames).forEach(function (item, i, arr) {
    if (arr[i].gameState === consts.GS_GAME_DELETE) {
        delete arr[i];
    }
});
```

It just not works, because arr is array (not associative array).

When I try to:

```
Object.keys(this.currentGames).forEach(function (item) {
    if (this.currentGames[item].gameState === consts.GS_GAME_DELETE) {
        delete this.currentGames[item];
    }
});
```

I get run-time error:

```
if (this.currentGames[item].gameState === consts.GS_GAME_DELETE) {
        ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentGames' of undefined

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and JSLint.NET.

So, my question is: is where right way for deleting element from associative array in cycle? Or is where way to shut JSLint up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var game in this.currentGames) {
  if (this.currentGames.hasOwnProperty(game)
    && this.currentGames[game].gameState === consts.GS_GAME_DELETE
  ) {
    delete this.currentGames[game];
  }
}
```

You also may use your last variant by define some variable with `this` value out of anonymous function scope (which has its own `this` context):

```
var self = this;
Object.keys(this.currentGames).forEach(function (item) {
  if (self.currentGames[item].gameState === consts.GS_GAME_DELETE) {
    delete self.currentGames[item];
  }
});
```

Comment: Your first variant generate the same warning: JSLint : Unexpected 'var'. The second variant works without warnings, but why I should do it this way? I think, it's ugly old syntax (I mean, using 'self').

Comment: Use the second, it's absolutely normal. Rename `self` variable as you wish.

Comment: As I see, JSLint doesn't allow `for` loops using without respective tolerate option, but `for-in` loops disallowed in total.

Comment: Thank you for help.I think, that discussion why JSLint generate such warnings and which method faster and more readable is beyound the scope of my question.